# Notifiy user Xamarin Forms SQL Server Push Notifications

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, websocket, signalr, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an app with xamarin ( iOS and Android ) using SQL Server as the backend database (AWS) , and I have a requirement that when user (TestUser) insert data
for example
Table Event

```
id | name | date_event |
1  | TestUser| 2022-07-04 17:30
```

the user (TestUser) will receive a notification before 10 min as reminder.

and another requirement  , the same user TestUser , can upload files , in this case all users in database must receive this information as a notification. for example all users in database will receive a notification  ( UesrUser uploaded new files" )

The app consume rest api  service.

i found Firebase Cloud Messaging, but with fcm we can only send a notification manually to all users.

i found also Websockets and Signal/R library, i don't know if it's utile in my case

Can anyone tell me how to implement this feature ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean an actual platform Push Notification, or some custom in-app notification?

Comment: yes custom in-app notification

Comment: SignalR would be my first choice

Comment: SignalR and websockts was the best solution in my case @Jason thank u